# Is it possible to do a Angular Routing based on path name to the component implicitly?

Tags: angular

Instead of explicitly matching the component for the route like below, Can we write a routing logic to find the component based on route name, as done in asp.net mvc default routes.

```
const appRoutes:Routes = 
[
{path:'list',component:ListComponent},
{path:'',redirectTo:'/list',pathMatch:'full'}

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options; 

One, explicitly name all the child routes:

```
const appRoutes:Routes = 
[
   {
     path:'list',
     children:[
        {path:'/componentName',pathMatch:'full', component: NamedComponent}
     ]
   },
   {path:'',redirectTo:'/list',pathMatch:'full'}
];
```

Two, create a redirection component where you pick the value from the uri and then redirect. However this is fairly redundant because you would have to still define all the routes anyway.

I do not believe there is a paradigm similar to automatically hitting controller actions like in mvc.